# remove colons from macaddress in ansible

Tags: ansible-facts

I need to create a file from an ansbile fact such as ansible_default_ipv4.macaddress by removing the colons from the mac address

I've tried everything I could think of and can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `replace` filter to replace the colons with nothing.

For example, to just write the mac address without colons to a file:

`- copy: content="{{ansible_default_ipv4.macaddress|replace(':','')}}" dest=/path/to/file`

[List of Jinja2 builtin filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters)

Comment: thanks.  my problem is the interface is variable.  ansible_{{ interface }}

Comment: I can't seem to get the mac address

Comment: The file name is the mac address without colons